# How to handle a click on a <tr> but not on the child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, tablerow

I handling the click with following code.

Table with input

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>​
```

Click handler

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n96eW/

It's working well, but if I have a checkbox in the td, it's handling it too when clicked.

Is there a way to handle the click of the TR but not trigger on the child elements?

Answer (score 15):

http://jsfiddle.net/n96eW/1/

Add another event handler in your checkbox to stopPropagation:

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});

$('table tr input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
​
```

Answer (score 4):

You can check `event.target` to filter your events:

```
$('table tr').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "input") {
        alert('clicked');
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
$("tr").on('click',function() {

  if (!$(event.target).is('input'))
    alert('clicked');

});
```